# Unique visitors online with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so I'm using a PHP script and MySQL to display the amount of visitors online. I'm calling the function on every page and need a way to avoid having duplicate entries from the same person during the same session.

It works fine but increments a visitor for every page load. I thought that having a 'require_once' statement on the session variable would work but nope. Below is the PHP code, please help!

```
//users online
function update_user_time()

{

    session_start();
    $session=session_id();
    $time=time();
    $time_check=$time-600; //SET TIME 10 minutes

    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="______"; // Mysql username
    $password="______"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="______"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="______"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select databse
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE session='$session'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count=="0"){

    $sql1="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(session, time)VALUES('$session', '$time')";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }

    else {
    "$sql2=UPDATE $tbl_name SET time='$time' WHERE session = '$session'";
    $result2=mysql_query($sql2);
    }

    $sql3="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
    $result3=mysql_query($sql3);
    $count_user_online=mysql_num_rows($result3);
    echo "[ $count_user_online users online ]";

    // if over 10 minute, delete session 
    $sql4="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE time<$time_check";
    $result4=mysql_query($sql4);

    // Open multiple browser page for result


    // Close connection
    mysql_close();

}
```

Comment: You should insert/update using REPLACE INTO https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html That way if it is not already there it will be inserted, otherwise if it is already there will just be replaced and not duplicated. A lot simpler than making separate queries for for if it exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would set a session variable, and only increment the visitor counter when that session variable has not been set.

Comment: You mean replace the current $session variable?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['counted']))
{
    $_SESSION['counted'] = TRUE;
    /* ADD TO COUNTER */
}
```

That way, only the first entry to the web site will get counted.  This is not 100% foolproof for a variety of fairly arcane reasons, but it's a good enough solution for most web sites.  HTH, ~Ray

Comment: Okay, I have hardly any experience in PHP/mysql so can you assist any further?

Add your if statement below the session_start or replace it with the current if($count==0)?